# Show that $\{a^ib^jc^{2j}\mid i\ge 0,j\ge 0\}$ is not regular

Tags: computer-science, automata, regular-expressions, pumping-lemma

How can I show this?I don't know how to start.

> Show that the set given below is not regular. $$\{a^ib^jc^{2j}\mid i\ge 0,j\ge 0\}$$

Comment: See [how to prove that a language is not regular?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular) over at CS.SE.

Comment: You want to use the [pumping lemma for regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages); if $p$ is the pumping length, start with the word $b^pc^{2p}$. (If you search the site, you’ll find many examples of such arguments.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I did that part on my own but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: @bambam: **Nehorai**’s answer could use a bit more detail, but it’s correct. Let $r=|u|$ and $s=|v|$; we know that $r+s\le p$ and $s\ge 1$. The first $r+s$ letters of $b^pc^{2p}$ are all $b$, so $u=b^r$, $v=b^s$, and $w=b^{p-r-s}c^{2p}$, the rest of the word. Thus, $$uv^kw=b^rb^{ks}b^{p-r-s}c^{2p} = b^{p+(k-1)s}c^{2p}\;.$$ But this is in your language if and only if $k=1$: if $k\ne 1$, the number of $c$s is not twice the number of $b$s. If the language were regular, $uv^kw$ would be in the language for *every* $k\ge 0$. Therefore the language is not regular.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott for $a^i$ we set $i=0$ since it satisfies $i \ge 0$.Am I right?

Comment: @bambam: Yes, the word $b^pc^{2p}$ is in the language because it is of the form $a^ib^jc^{2j}$ with $i,j\ge 0$, specifically, with $i=0$ and $j=p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the language is regular, I will use **Brian M.scott**'s idea if $p$ is the pumping leangth choose the word $z:=b^pc^{2p}$, we will use the pumping lemma for regulal languages

$|z|>p$ so $z=uvw$ such that

1. $|uv|\leqslant p$
2. $|v|\geqslant 1$
3. $uv^iw\in \mathcal L\quad i\geqslant 0$

For $i=2$ or $i=0$ the word is not in the language, therefore the language isn't regular.

Comment: Isn't it the proof of $ \{b^jc^{2j}\mid j\ge 0\} $  ?

Comment: @bambam Yes it is, **but** it's also proof for *your* language the same that in the question, because the pumping lemma says that **every** string $w$ in $\mathcal L$ of length $p$ satisfying  the three conditions. And here  $b^pc^{2p}$ is in the language so you can apply the pumping lemma on $w$

Comment: Didn't you apply the pumping lemma on w? I did not understand how to continue.

Comment: @bambam That's it, we got contradiction therefore the language isn't regular.

Comment: I think we should continue, are you sure?

Comment: @bambam You always  can add some of your explanations in the answer, but I will let you do it by yourself as an exercise, take the time and read about the pumping lemma and see some examples.

Comment: I voted up since it is useful but not the full answer in my opinion.Thanks

Comment: @bambam Actually it is a full answer, all you need to think in those type of questions is what word you should choose and which  $i$ will give contradiction.

Comment: $w=uvw$ is this part true? I mean there is two w's.

Comment: @bambam No, it is not true I fixed that